# Simple 2d version of Sobolev embedding theorem

Tags: analysis

I'm having trouble understanding the last few steps in a proof of the Sobolev embedding theorem in 2d, especially the last step.  Here $g(x)=1$ for $x∈[0,1/2]$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x∈[3/4,\infty)$.

$$
||r^{k-2}||_{L^{q}(B(0,1))}\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}||D^\alpha (gu)||_{L^{p}(B(0,1))} \leq C \biggl[\int_0^1 r^{p(k-2)/(p-1)}rdr\biggr]^{(p-1)/p}   ||u||_{W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^2)}
$$

This is from page 19 of [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf)

I'm also not sure about the previous step.  I suppose the functions of $\theta$ go away because they are finite when we integrate over them.  But how do we get rid of $g(x)$ in the last step?  Please spell it out in complete detail as I'm just a physicist!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: My problem is that I don't see how to get rid of the derivatives of $g(x)$ that occur on the left hand side.